# "For" loop in bash script only run once

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop

The script goal is simple.

I have many directory which contains some captured traffic files.
I want to run a command for each directory. So I came up with a script. But I don't know why the script is run only with the first match.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Collect throughput from a group of directory containing capture files
# Group of directory can be specify by pattern
# Usage: ./collectThroughputList [regex]
#       [regex] is the name pattern of the group of directory

for DIR in $( ls -d $1 ); do
   if test -d "$DIR"; then
       echo Collecting throughputs from directory: "$DIR"
       ( sh collectThroughput.sh $DIR > $DIR.txt )
   fi
done
   echo Done\!
```

I try it with:

```
for DIR in $1; do
```

or

```
for DIR in `ls -d $1`; do
```

or

```
for DIR in $( ls -d "$1" ); do
```

or

```
for DIR in $( ls -d $1 ); do
```

But the result is the same. The for loop runs only one time.

Finally I found this one and did some tricks for it to work. However, I would like to know why my first script doesn't work.

```
find *Delay50ms* -type d -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && echo enter '{}' && ../collectThroughput.sh ../'{}' > ../'{}'.txt" \;
```

"*Delay*" is the directory pattern name that I want to run the command with.
Thanks for pointing out the issues.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

Most probably the problem you are encountering is due to the fact that you are trying to use some kind of pattern like `*` as argument to your script.

Running it with something like:

```
my_script *
```

What's happening here is, that the shell will expand `*` prior to calling your script.
Thus after word splitting has been performed `$1` in your script will just reference the first entry returned by `ls`.

### Example

Given the following directory layout:

```
 directory_a
 directory_b
 directory_c
```

Calling `my_script *` will result in:

```
my_script directory_a  directory_b directory_c
```

being called thus your loop just iterating over `$(ls -d directory_a)` which in fact is nothing else but `directory_a` alone.

### Solution

To have the program run with `$1=*` you would have to escape the `*` prior to calling your script.

Try running:

```
my_script \*
```

To see it effectively does what it is intended to do then. This way `$1` in your script will contain `*` instead of `directory_a` which most probably is the way you wanted your script to work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problems. However, I don't like the solution since we have to do some tricks on the use of the script. It would later causes problems to the people following the project.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to find all sub-directories under $1, use it like this:

```
for DIR in $(find $1 -type d)
```

Comment: Why does this get upvoted? 1. This is not equal to the OP's approach (it searches recursively) 2. [Thou shalt not do this either](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). 3. Unquoted `$1`.

Comment: I withdraw 1. (sorry, didn't look closely enough), but 2 and 3 still stand.

Answer (score 1):

as mikyra has pointed out, the shell expands your argument `*` to all entries in your directory prior to passing it to your script.

if you want shell-expansion of your wildcards (e.g. `*` matches all but hidden files), you could simply leave the expansion to the shell and use the result, by iterating over all arguments, rather than just the first one:

```
for DIR in $@; do
   # ...
done
```

if you want to do the expansion yourself (e.g. because the pattern should be applied only to a pre-filtered list or to files in a different directory, or because you want regex-expansion rather than shell globbing), you have to protect the argument from being expanded by the shell, either using backslash notation (like mikyra's `\*`) or by using quotes (which is often easier to use):

```
my_script "*"
```